# Change checkbox style for razor asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to ASP.NET and I have following problem:

I'm using this code to change CheckBox and bind a label to it:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "css-checkbox", id=Html.NameFor(m => m.UserName)})
<label class = "css-checkbox" for="@Html.NameFor(m => m.UserName)"></label>
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
```

To be able to use this code from CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
   position:absolute; 
   z-index:-1000; 
   left:-1000px; 
   overflow: hidden; 
   clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
   height:1px; 
   width:1px; 
   margin:-1px; 
   padding:0; 
   border:0;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
   padding-left:55px;
   height:50px; 
   display:inline-block;
   line-height:50px;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position: 0 0;
   font-size:50px;
   vertical-align:middle;
   cursor:pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
   background-position: 0 -50px;
}

label.css-label {
   background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_306b54046314f79a72ea1d0abe22fb0e.png);
   -webkit-touch-callout: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

But unfortunately this error is showing up:

> Error  12  `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MYNAMESPACE.Models.LogOnModel>` does not contain a definition for `NameFor` and no extension method `NameFor` accepting a first argument of type `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MYNAMESPACE.Models.LogOnModel>` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

I added this code:

```
namespace MYNAMESPACE
{    
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static string NameFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            return htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
        }

        public static string IdFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            return HtmlHelper.GenerateIdFromName(NameFor(htmlHelper, expression));
        }
    }
}
```

and this to web.config

```
<pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
        <add namespace="MYNAMESPACE"/>
      </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Does anyone know why error keeps showing up? Or maybe there is simpler method to remove border from checkboxes?

Comment: use @id instead of id after `@class = "css-checkbox",`

Comment: Make sure that you have put `using System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper;` in your class file

Comment: MVC already includes `IdFor()` and `NameFor()` methods - why are you creating your own?

Comment: And you css selectors will never work anyway - `@CheckBoxFor()` generate 2 elements - a `<input type="checkbox" ... />` and `<input type="hidden ... />`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added these methods when I got error saying "System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'NameFor' "
and css selectors are from this generator: http://www.csscheckbox.com/
are you sure they will not work? If so do you know any working generator?

Comment: @Riki - Got this inside System.Web.Mvc and other methods are working.

Comment: @Raviteja - thx, but it still does not work

Comment: No, you selectors will not work. The `CheckBoxFor()` method generates 2 inputs so `input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {` is undefined (the next element after the `<input type="checkbox" ... />`is a hidden input (not the label). And in any case you give the label `class="css-checkbox"` (not `css-label`) but that's irrelevant.

Comment: But what is the point of add a manual label element? And why are you then adding `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)` which adds another `<label>` element but because you changed the `id` of the checkbox, it now longer works as a label. What your doing can simply be done by removing `id=Html.NameFor(m => m.UserName` and the manual `<label>` element and adding `new { @class = "css-label" }` to the `LabelFor()` method (but you still need to fix the css selectors)

Comment: I thought that this label should work as image of checked and unchecked checkbox after hiding the original one. Second label is normal label. What I want is the removal of checkbox border and this solution is what I found in the web.

Answer (score 0):

`NameFor()` and `IdFor()` comes from `System.Web.Mvc.Html`.
You don't need to define those extensions in your own namespace.
Just add `@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;` on top of your cshtml file.